# new instagram api hashtag search disabled? or how to display hashtag and public content?

Tags: instagram-api

I'm new to the instagram api and after going through the documentation and following the instruction i got this error

> next_max_id and min_id are deprecated for this endpoint; use
>   min_tag_id and max_tag_id instead

So, then i went to permissions tab of my client and there i saw this. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x17jj.jpg)

Can you please help why it is not supported. And why does instagram also state

> As alternative solution, you can show your own Instagram content,
>
> **or find a company that offers this type of service (content discover,
>   moderation, and display).**

.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same situation today. Looks like you can only get data from your own feed (self) or the one of people in the sandbox...

If you are in one of the 3 last situation of the "Permission Review", you can ask for more data access like "public_content".

I'll try to find a way around too...

Comment: I have the same problem, hope that someone can help us to fix this one soon!